# File not found error after converting python file to exe

Tags: python, sharepoint, pyinstaller

I have python script for SharePoint login (using python office365-rest-python-client) and download a file. I would like to convert script to executable file so i can share it with non-technical people. Python code run fine but when i convert it to exe using Pyinstaller and try to run, it gives me FileNotFoundError.

I am relatively new to python and i tried couple of tutorial and solution found online but no luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 107, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 35, in SPLogin
  File "site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\authentication_context.py", line 18, in acquire_token_for_user
  File "site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\saml_token_provider.py", line 57, in acquire_token
  File "site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\saml_token_provider.py", line 82, in acquire_service_token
  File "site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\saml_token_provider.py", line 147, in prepare_security_token_request
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\foo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI66362\\office365\\runtime\\auth\\SAML.xml'
[6664] Failed to execute script test
```

See below spec file.

SAML.xml location:  C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\SAML.xml

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Foo\\Downloads\\sptest\\newbuild'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=['.'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Comment: an obvious question, but: does the file `'C:\\Users\\foo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI66362\\office365\\runtime\\auth\\SAML.xml'` exist?

Comment: Can't tell for sure. _MEI66362 folder delete itself as soon as exe complete the run or  in this case hit the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a copy of `SAML.xml` (in my test case, right next to my python script `test0.py`); you can copy/paste from [this page](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/master/office365/runtime/auth/providers/templates/SAML.xml). Then run:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "SAML.xml;office365/runtime/auth" test0.py
```

Comment: @MikeCode Awesome! Make sure to accept Zaki's answer, then; it'll mark this question as solved, and give Zaki a nice reputation boost as a reward for solving your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The `_MEI66362` folder is created when you execute a `Pyinstaller` created `.exe`. It will contain everything that `Pyinstaller` determined is needed by your application. However, it cannot deduce every file that your app needs. In some cases, you must tell `Pyinstaller` about needed resources. You can use the `-add-data` and `--add-binary` options (or the `datas` and `binaries` class members in a `.spec` file). See the documentation [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) and [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle).

In your `datas=` statement, the second argument is where the file should be saved in your executable. So you must place it in the folder where `saml_token_provider.py` is looking for it. I think you should use something like `datas=[ ('/pathtofolder/SAML.xml', 'office365/runtime/auth') ],`.

Comment: I have tried both: `pyinstaller —add-data ‘SAML.xml;SAML.xml’ test.py` and added  `Datas =[(‘/pathtofolder/SAML.xml’, ‘.’)]` in test.spec file but no luck, getting same error.
I check the folder that created with all dependencies in `dist` folder with exe file, it’s missing ‘office365’ module.

Comment: I have added to my above answer. I think my solution is correct, but have no way to test it.

Comment: Try running `pyi-archive_viewer -br <executable_name>`. That should list everything in your executable. Look for `SAML.xml` in the list. Just a reminder, if you run `pyinstaller` and give it a `test.py` file, it overwrites any existing `test.spec`. If you run `pyinstaller` with the `test.spec` argument, it ignores almost all command line options.

Comment: Thanks John! Its still not resolved. Moving away from pyinstaller for now, looking for other options to see if i can get any success.

Comment: If you are willing to give it one more try, please post your `test.spec` file.

Comment: Sure, just added new clutter free spec file in my question.