# FileNotFoundError: while converting .py to exe file

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert my py file to exe after when I run the exe file it always shows the same error on console windows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "njlispendens.py", line 482, in <module>
  File "selenium_stealth\__init__.py", line 45, in stealth
  File "selenium_stealth\utils.py", line 8, in with_utils
  File "pathlib.py", line 1132, in read_text
  File "pathlib.py", line 1117, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\alium\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI93442\\selenium_stealth\\js\\utils.js'
[9744] Failed to execute script 'njlispendens' due to unhandled exception!
[10772:940:0102/104425.600:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(226)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[10772:6564:0102/104425.600:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [10:44:25.611] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[10772:940:0102/104425.616:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(229)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[10772:940:0102/104425.616:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(232)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[10772:940:0102/104425.709:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
```

Here is what I did to deal with the error

1. tried uninstalling packages and installing them again and then converting it into exe
2. tried Pyinstaller single and multiple file
3. adding python to path
4. tried using auto-py-to-exe to for conversion
5. tried uninstalling python, removing from path, installing python again

please help

Comment: Do not post images of text. Post it as plain (formatted if needed) text

Comment: ok thanks I will next time

Comment: @UmarMughal you can edit your question and remove the (illegible) image and paste a copy of the relevant text instead.

Comment: From what I think I can make out in the picture, my first guess would be that you're running it on another computer than where you built it and it's unable to find some things that it was able to find on the compute where you built it.

Comment: No Grismar I'm running on same sytem. I've been converting py to exe before. but after installing new windows in my stem I'm getting this problem. yesterday I've problem with the Pandas in another py file and today the problem is with the Selenium_Stealth

Comment: maybe pyinstaller failed to recognise a necessary file needed to execute your code and add it with the package. Make sure that the `util.js` is present at the specified path. Try solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702300/file-not-found-error-after-converting-python-file-to-exe) if that is the case.